# complex on function handler Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i was just looking at the source of button.js and came across the following snippet of code :

```
$(document).on('click.bs.button.data-api', '[data-toggle^="button"]', function (e) {
    var $btn = $(e.target)
    if (!$btn.hasClass('btn')) $btn = $btn.closest('.btn')
    Plugin.call($btn, 'toggle')
    e.preventDefault()
  })
```

I am not new to Jquery but i am quite a beginner , now i understand how the on() function works in Jquery .

my question with the above piece of code is , i don't really understand the event being attached to the on() function , let me explain :

```
$(document).on('click.bs.button.data-api'
```

i don't quite understand what this event is :

```
click.bs.button.data-api
```

in normal Jquery code i usually see things like :

```
$('body').on('click' , '.btn' , function(e){
     // do something
});
```

but that one handler completely throws me off the hook , can somebody explain what exactly had the author of that code achieved by adding that handler ?

heres the link on the git repository of the plugin : [Line 106](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/button.js#L106)

Comment: Besides a few hard-coded into the DOM, events are pretty arbitrary and you can absolutely define new ones.

Comment: Maybe `click.bs.button.data-api` is a custom event? It could be triggered using `$(element).trigger('click.bs.button.data-api')`

Answer (score 2):

It's an event namespace.

Per the jQuery docs on [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> An event name can be qualified by event namespaces that simplify
> removing or triggering the event. For example, "`click.myPlugin.simple`"
> defines both the myPlugin and simple namespaces for this particular
> click event. A click event handler attached via that string could be
> removed with `.off("click.myPlugin")` or `.off("click.simple")` without
> disturbing other click handlers attached to the elements. Namespaces
> are similar to CSS classes in that they are not hierarchical; only one
> name needs to match. Namespaces beginning with an underscore are
> reserved for jQuery's use.

Answer (score 1):

`click.bs.button.data-api` is a click event event with namespace `bs.button.data-api`